# (Python - openpyxl) Can't import the exported xlsx file

Tags: python, import, export, xlsx, openpyxl

I'm using **openpyxl** to import/export xlsx files.

But I can't import `load_workbook()` the file that i exported with **openpyxl**.

I must open the exported xlsx file in Excel, change some value of the imported xlsx file and save it (its size changes also (for ex: from 148 Ko to 180 Ko). Then i can import it with **openpyxl**.

I think that there is a problem in export because after saving manually import works.

Thanks.

Comment: It is unclear where you import and export from. Are you using an external program that does use `import` and `export` or are you just using that terminology instead of `load_workbook()` and `Workbook.save()`. If you provide some code, that would be helpful preferably with something that creates the file that cannot be 'imported'. Did you try to read the faulty file with Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this doesn't currently work: https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/issue/46/problem-reading-one-excel-file-and-writing

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
ws.cell('A1').value = 1
wb.save('test.xslx')
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2.get_active_sheet()
ws2.cell('A2').value = 2
wb2.save('test2.xlsx')
```